# Vertical-align=bottom on image + text

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I have a table containing a set of elements. Because of the variable img size, i set a fixed height, and because of the possible overflowing of the text, the `text-overflow:ellipsis`, but I can't get the image+text on the bottom of the space available

[image http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/7893/immaginescr.png](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/7893/immaginescr.png)

```
<div class="game">
     <a href="url"><img src="(img src)"></a>
     <div class="gamedescription">-Metal Gear Solid<br>-PlayStation</div>
</div>
```

```css
.game {
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #8F8F8F;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

.gamedescription {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwpQZ/)

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.game {
position: relative;
width: 110px;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid #8F8F8F;
float: left;
height: 200px;
}

.gamedescription {
position: absolute;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
display: block;
bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="game">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"></a>
     <div class="gamedescription">-Metal Gear Solid<br>-PlayStation</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

You were missing position attribute from both

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted the whole image+text going on bottom.

Anyway, i figured out I was missing a div containing them all, and that's why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="game">
     <div class="Apply bottom properties here">
          <a href="url"><img src="(img src)"></a>
          <div class="gamedescription">-Metal Gear Solid<br>-PlayStation</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Css: using the one on the first post +

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 23px;
```

on the new div.